# Cannot access the variable set in class constructor

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am having a very frustrating issue. I set my variable in constructor like this:

```
export class ChannelTransition{
    constructor(props) {
        this.transitionHandler=props;
    }

    channelTransitionSetup(channelsList) {
        console.log(this.transitionHandler.handleHeaderTransition);            
    }
}
```

And now when I try to access that variable set on constructor I get undefined. I know it has sth to do with scope but then how can I access my variable in constructor?

Comment: Make sure your `transitionHandler` has a property called `handleHeaderTransition`? Otherwise this is correct.

Comment: And where and how channelTransitionSetup is called?

Comment: Does `props` has any property named `handleHeaderTransition`? Did you debugged the code? What values did you get in the constructor for `transitionHandler` after setting it? what values are you getting inside `channelTransitionSetup` for `transitionHandler` before calling `this.transitionHandler.handleHeaderTransition`?

Comment: First I make an object of the class and then I call channelTransitionSetup. So I am sure I am calling it properly. Even when I use console.log in constructor I am able to see the right result

Comment: @palaѕн Yes it has and even I am able to see it in constructor but in the function maybe because of this scope it returns undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works out for me:

```
    class ChannelTransition{
        constructor(props) {
            this.transitionHandler=props;
        }
        channelTransitionSetup(channelsList) {
            console.log(this.transitionHandler.handleHeaderTransition);

        }

    }


    let test = new ChannelTransition({handleHeaderTransition:'Ok!'});

    test.channelTransitionSetup();
/* This print 'Ok!' in console */
```

So I do not know what is your problem. Can you explain how do you use it?

Comment: Thanks for answering: here is how I am calling it:  let channelTransition = new ChannelTransition(this.props.handleHeaderTransition);
        channelTransition.changeChannelOnScroll(channelNames);  and then in changeChannelOnScroll I have this.channelTransitionSetup(channelsList);

Comment: Also I just simplified the above code and there is a reason that I do not use the channelTransitionSetup directly

Comment: I think I found the issue . Your example helped me  a lot. So I was going one too many level down in the object hierarchy. Instead if I call  it this way it works: this.transitionHandler() instead of this.transitionHandler.handleHeaderTransition(). Thanks for the help

Comment: It's a pleasure. If you get any other problem just ask over here :)